# SqlDataSource Error Handling

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I am just trying to handle the code if some errors happens to connection string. I got this error when build the solution

> does not contain a definition for 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' and no extension method 'SqlDataSource1_Selecting' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.webform1_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Markup:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server"  
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ayman %>"
        SelectCommand ="Select au_id,au_lname,au_fname from authors where 1=1"  
        OnSelecting="SqlDataSource1_Selecting"  />
```

Code:

```
protected void SqlDataSource1_Selecting(object sender, SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Exception != null)
    {
        lblError.Text = "An exception occurred performing the query.";
        // Consider the error handled.
        e.ExceptionHandled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you mean with "errors happen to connectiom string"? Do you want to handle errors for connecting to the database?

Comment: yes actually that what i want